psycopg3 mogrify: AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'mogrify'
Im using psycopg3 and would like to see what the actual sql with the parameters is so i can execute it using dbweaver...
         with psycopg.connect(self.connect_str, autocommit=True) as conn:
            if self.log.level == logging.DEBUG:
                  cur = conn.cursor()
                  sql_mogr = cur.mogrify(sql, params)
                  self.log.debug(sql_mogr)
            else:
               self.log.info(f'sql: {sql}, params:{params}')

            df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = conn, params = params)

The results of the mogrify line is:
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'mogrify'

Does psycopg3 not support this method?  if not, what is an alternate solution?
version of psycopg:
psycopg==3.1.18
psycopg-binary==3.1.18
psycopg-pool==3.2.1


What version of psycopg3 have you got? mogrify was added in 3.1.

i just have this in requirements psycopg[binary,pool], i'd imagine that would get the latest.  but let me figure out how to determine the version

i have 3.1.  i added the info to the question

The mogrify method is only available on the ClientCursor class.
>>> conn = psycopg.connect(dbname='test', cursor_factory=psycopg.ClientCursor)
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> q = """select * from users"""

>>> cur.mogrify(q)
'select * from users'


thanks. do u know if using a client cursor would impact performance much?

@mike01010. Read this section Client vs Server binding for the pros and cons of each.
